# error in implementation of dijkstra's algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dijkstra

i have made this code according to the pseudocode given in wiki. still there are some errors. please help me with the coding and tell me how can i improve it i am trying it from hours ! 
i have marked the line where i know there as an error . and rest i dont know where am i wrong

```
  var graph = [{
        from: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        to: [3, 3, 5, 6]
    }];
    var shortestpath = function (graph, source) {
            for (i in graph) {
                dist[i] = infinty;
                prev[i] = undefined;
            }
            dist[source] = 0;
            var q = [];
            q.push(graph.value);
            while (q != 0) {
               var min_distance = infinity;
var u = null;

for (var i in dist) {
   if (dist[i] < min_distance) {
      u = i;
      min_distance = dist[u];
   }
}
                if (dist[u] = infinity) {
                    break;
                }
                q.pop(u);
                for (v in u) {
                    var alt = dist[u] + dist_between(u, v);
                    if (alt < dist[v]) {
                        dist[v] = alt;
                        previous[v] = u;
                        q.sort(v);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dist;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Dijkstra's algorithm pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode),  `u`  should not be a **list**, but a simple int holding the index of the vertex having the small distance in  `Q`.

If you want the vertex with the smallest distance, you've to iterate over the vertices array , keep track of the min distance found so far, and assign to  `u` the vertex having this ditance.

```
var min_distance = infinity;
var u = null;

for (var i in dist) {
   if (dist[i] < min_distance) {
      u = i;
      min_distance = dist[u];
   }
}
```

Comment: please check if i have made the correct changes. and if no ples edit it.